# How do I tell if external javascript is either not running or not echoing? And why

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

The code below works on one page, but not another page (the place it should be - the same place as on the other page) - is blank.

This code displays the facebook like button, and is copied verbatim from the facebook website.
    The code is there - I checked "view page source" in Firefox, it just isn't doing anything.

I can put another script, the "find us on facebook" button, either directly above or below this code, and that shows up okay.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like 
href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/[our name]/[our number]" layout="box_count" 
show_faces="false" width="50"></fb:like>
```

UPDATE
If I use the iframe code instead of the XFBML code from: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ then it works on both pages (but I can't format that right - Wordpress doesn't like iframes in widgets).
What is going on?

UPDATE
When I disable the Wordpress Facebook Share plugin this problem goes away.  There may be a problem with double initialization of the Facebook SDK, as pointed out by Chris Livey below. Is there some html I can add before the "like" code to de-initialize the SDK?

Comment: Okay, I have a few questions now.  First are the two pages that you have this code on within the same website?  If not, is the second page accessed by IP address or a regular domain name?  Next, what other differences (javascript wise) exist between the two pages?

Comment: Also, which browser are you using to look at the pages?  If it's IE8, is compatibility mode turned on for one of the pages?

Comment: Finally, the items you have in [our name] and [our number], are they identical in the two pages?

Comment: The two pages are on the same site.  The code is the same (that section) on the two pages.  I'm using Firefox. I tried Opera, and got the same results. The two items (name/number) are the same on both pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned Firefox.  You should start with looking in the Tools | Error Console to see if any javascript errors occurred during the page load.

The next step is to get the firebug addon and use it to see what might be happening.

**(removed update - info did not apply)**

**UPDATE**:

Okay, the word press plug in clobbering you.  If you are going to keep the word press plug in then remove this:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

From your button code and everything should work just fine.

**UPDATE 2**:
From all of the comments, this issue boiled down to a word press plugin using it's own javascript definition for the FB object.  Fortunately before creating that object it performs a test to see if FB is already defined.

The fix then is to add the correct FB script to the top of the page such that it is executed by the browser BEFORE the word press FB Share button plugin script.  Because it is executed first, the word press plugin can't screw it up while continuing to function correctly.

This only works if the browser executes the scripts in the order seen on the page.

The real fix would be for the word press plugin to be modified to use the full FB object from connect.facebook.com instead of the smaller one it provides.

Comment: That Firefox error console is one busy bee. Hotmail's site is giving constant warnings, as are other tabs. There's one "error" on the page that is not on the other one - "FB.provide is not a function" " http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" -and when I click on that there's a bunch of highlighted code: "FB.provide('Array',{indexOf:function(a,c){if(a.indexOf)return -too long to post here.

Comment: That error indicates that the facebook core javascript stuff is either not referenced on your page OR it isn't executing in order to create the FB object.  I'd start with checking that both pages have the same `<script>` tags

Comment: I agree with Chris; has the Facebook SDK been initialized on the page?

Comment: The code is identical.  It's in a SidebarOther "widget" in Wordpress.  The widget items appear on the right side.  It's the same "theme" for both pages - you only put it in one place. All the other items is the sidebars appear as they are supposed to.

Comment: I installed Firebug. When I move the cursor over that code, nothing is highlighted on the page.

Comment: There's a difference seen with Firebug. See other answer's comments.

Comment: You don't need an app id or to register the application to put a facebook like button on your page.  And if that was the case, why is it working on the other page - same web server, domain, etc.  See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Comment: @harold: apparently I missed the part where the sdk was being included by the code you showed.  Not sure how I skipped that ;).  Anyway, please answer the questions I added to the original question.

Comment: I added an update to the question - If I use the idiv code instead of the XFBML code from: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like then it works on both pages (but I can't format that right). What is going on?

Comment: @harold: This boils down to something preventing the page from executing the fb script.  It could be as simple as you have the script command in the second page twice.  If that's the case it's possible that the fb object is trying to initialize twice and killing both instances in the process.  Could you use pastebin.com to post the full source of the problem page?

Comment: You want me to do "view page source" in Firefox, and then post that to pastebin.com?  Or is there some way to use Firebug to get more complete source (the external script code), and you want that?

Comment: I can tell you now, as I searched for the string on the Firefox view source page, that there is only one instance of "<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">... on the page. (See comment above.)

Comment: The owner doesn't want the source published. I know that anyone can do "view page source" in Firefox...

Comment: I think you are right about a double initialization problem.  If I deactivate the "Facebook Share" Wordpress plugin the problem goes away. (That plugin adds an icon at the end of articles.)  That plugin doesn't have any icons on the listing page, so that one worked okay.  Is there some html I can add before the "like" code to de-initialize the SDK?

Comment: @harold: Just take out the `<script src="connect....` part, renable your plug in and you should be good

Comment: The like button is not appearing w/o that first <script src ...> part. The share plugin is installed, and that button is there. The <fb: like ...> code is greyed out in Firefug.

Comment: Sounds like a catch 22.  Either you use the wordpress plugin or you hand add your own fb links.  I think you're going to have to pick one.  Are their any options on the WordPress plugin, such as "don't init facebook api?"

Comment: You can edit the plug-in code after it's installed. I posted the plugin's code here: http://pastebin.com/4V6Mf8KZ
I don't see an all.js initialization call. It's php.

Comment: @harold: Lines 621 and 679 are where the plugin code is injecting a script resource that defines the FB javascript object. This is in conflict with the one from connect.facebook.net. You might try adding the script link to connect.facebook.net to the top of your page in order to get it to execute BEFORE the plugin's version.

Comment: Brilliant.  That solved the problem. I added the `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>` before the Facebook Share code, and now the like button works.  The share button still works too.

Comment: Chris - Please update the answer to reflect this so people can see it easier. I added the update, but it's not there.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have firebug? If not I would recommend downloading it:
http://getfirebug.com/

It has a console that lets you know exactly what is going wrong in JavaScript land.

Comment: See the other answer for my comment on what's in the Firefox error console. I'll install Firebug in a moment.

Comment: Okay. I installed Firebug.  When I move the cursor over that code, nothing is highlighted on the page.

Comment: I am assuming your code does not actually say: pages/[our name]/[our number]

Comment: As a debug, have you tried just the vanilla version of the like button on this page, meaning without the URL?

Comment: There's a difference shown by Firefug: on the page that doesn't work the following is grayed out "fb:like width="50"..."  That's right below the "script src=" line.  It's loading all.js - you can hit the '+' and see the code. That code is the same in both places.

Comment: The vanilla version doesn't appear either.

Comment: Not doubting you, just trying to get a feel for where the bug might be: you have xfbml  : true in FB.init() on the page you are trying to get it working correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how to determine that: "xfbml : true in FB.init()"  That's not my code (it's "xfbml=1", above). I guess you are talking about using Firebug?  I can't figure out how to step through the displayed all.js code (from the external site) with Firebug to see the values to see how that long "if" statement at the beginning of all.js is being evaluated.

Comment: When you initialize the Facebook SDK: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/


Does yours look like the first box shown?

Comment: Registering the app is not needed for just adding the like button. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Comment: I added an update to the question - If I use the idiv code instead of the XFBML code from: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/  then it works on both pages (but I can't format that right). What is going on?

Comment: What I meant by "registering an app" 2 comments up is that I haven't "initialized the Facebook SDK" - that's for other stuff. I don't have an app id, and haven't needed on for adding like buttons.  I've put them on a completely different website, and the like button works on the other page on this website.

Comment: Even if you don't need an app id, you still have to initialize the SDK to use the XFBML. The like button page says, "The XFBML version is more versatile, but requires use of the JavaScript SDK." http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Comment: @Chris: I think the sdk is automatically initialized by including the script reference to all.js.  I think if he posts the actual html generated for the page to pastebin we'll be able to actually identify what has happened.

Comment: How do I do that? ("if he posts the actual html generated for the page to pastebin") I've tried looking for that with Firebug.

Comment: @harold: just do a view source in firefox.  Then copy ALL of the html over to pastebin.com.  Finally, update your question with a link to your source at pastebin

Comment: I have updated the problem with new info - disabling the Facebook share plugin fixes the problem.  Is there html code to de-initialize the Facebook SDK that I can add before the "like" code?  (The owner doesn't want the source published. I know that anyone can do "view page source" in Firefox...)

Comment: What if you used the XFBML but loaded it from an iframe you created? You could then control the styling from within iframe.

Comment: Or what if you modified the wordpress plugin and removed the SDK from it so that you could correctly place it and have it load one time?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. What worked is the last comment on the other answer.